# How can I include null values in a MIN or MAX?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table where I am storing timespan data. the table has a schema similar to:

```
ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)   
RecordID INT NOT NULL  
StartDate DATE NOT NULL  
EndDate DATE NULL
```

And I am trying to work out the start and end dates for each record id, so the minimum StartDate and maximum EndDate. StartDate is not nullable so I don't need to worry about this but I need the MAX(EndDate) to signify that this is currently a running timespan.

It is important that I maintain the NULL value of the EndDate and treat this as the maximum value.

The most simple attempt (below) doesn't work highlighting the problem that MIN and MAX will ignore NULLS (source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179916.aspx).

```
SELECT recordid, MIN(startdate), MAX(enddate) FROM tmp GROUP BY recordid
```

I have created an SQL Fiddle with the basic setup done.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0a75

How can I bend SQL Server 2008 to my will to produce the following result from the data given in the SQLFiddle?

```
RecordId  Start       End  
1         2009-06-19  NULL
2         2012-05-06  NULL
3         2013-01-25  NULL
4         2004-05-06  2009-12-01
```

Comment: don't understand - if I run `SELECT recordid, MIN(startdate), Max(enddate) FROM tmp GROUP BY recordid` then the null is preserved!

Comment: - the result you show in OP doesn't seem to relate to the sqlfiddle schema?

Comment: Take a look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/565dc/29 for sample data that is valid. If only one record exists for a grouping, the NULL will be preserved, otherwise it will be overridden by any date.

Comment: @whytheq, you right it does not. It is an example result.

Comment: I've updated the question so the results are valid for the sample data.

Comment: You also have a typo in the script `MIN(startdate), MIN(enddate) ` should read `MIN(startdate), MAX(enddate)`

Comment: I may have posted late, but please take a look at my answer anyway

Answer (score 105, accepted):

It's a bit ugly but because the `NULL`s have a special meaning to you, this is the cleanest way I can think to do it:

```
SELECT recordid, MIN(startdate),
   CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN enddate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
        THEN MAX(enddate)
   END
FROM tmp GROUP BY recordid
```

That is, if any row has a `NULL`, we want to force that to be the answer. Only if no rows contain a `NULL` should we return the `MIN` (or `MAX`).

Comment: +1 . . . But the OP really wants the maximum end date, despite the SQL ("so the minimum StartDate and maximum EndDate").

Comment: @GordonLinoff I actually want to maintain the NULL as the highest value. I have edited the question to clarify, thanks.

Answer (score 64):

The effect you want is to treat the NULL as the largest possible date then replace it with NULL again upon completion:

```
SELECT RecordId, MIN(StartDate), NULLIF(MAX(COALESCE(EndDate,'9999-12-31')),'9999-12-31') 
  FROM tmp GROUP BY RecordId
```

Per your fiddle this will return the exact results you specify under all conditions.

Comment: This is cleaner than the accepted answer IMO. I use a slight variation: `NULLIF(MAX(COALESCE(EndDate, 'infinity'::timestamp)), 'infinity'::timestamp)`

Comment: No idea what dbms that's for, but the question was for SQL server.

Comment: Note that in 8,000 years we'll need to review this code... but yeah, a lot cleaner than the accepted answer.

Comment: I believe @jbg's variation is PostgreSQL specific

Comment: Anyone looking for smallest date (i.e. start_date or similar), the smallest supported date in MySQL is `1000-01-01` [Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html)

Answer (score 28):

In my expression, `count(enddate)` counts how many rows where the `enddate` column is not null.
The `count(*)` expression counts total rows.
By comparing, you can easily tell if any value in the `enddate` column contains `null`. If they are identical, then `max(enddate)` is the result. Otherwise the `case` will default to returning `null` which is also the answer. This is a very popular way to do this exact check.

```
SELECT recordid, 
MIN(startdate), 
case when count(enddate) = count(*) then max(enddate) end
FROM tmp 
GROUP BY recordid
```

Comment: Passed my tests, including the new multiple nulls for a group even if this should never happen. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2c45b/2

Answer (score 8):

Use IsNull

```
SELECT recordid, MIN(startdate), MAX(IsNull(enddate, Getdate()))
FROM tmp 
GROUP BY recordid
```

I've modified MIN in the second instruction to MAX

Comment: or even better, **Coalesce**, which is ansi-sql compatible

Comment: Unfortunately I need to maintain the null as the high value. I've edited my question to be clearer on this.

Comment: the question is asking for max/min value of enddate. I fail to see how getdate can replace the lowest or the highest value in an unknown table it could be a calender table. I also fail to see the advanage of returning getdate instead of null.

Comment: The sample was incorrect, stating MIN rather than MAX for the EndDate column.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have only one record with null in EndDate column for a given RecordID, 
something like this should give you desired output :

```
WITH cte1 AS
(
SELECT recordid, MIN(startdate) as min_start , MAX(enddate) as max_end
FROM tmp 
GROUP BY recordid
)

SELECT a.recordid, a.min_start , 
CASE 
   WHEN b.recordid IS  NULL THEN a.max_end
END as max_end
FROM cte1 a
LEFT JOIN tmp b ON (b.recordid = a.recordid AND b.enddate IS NULL)
```

Comment: This does in fact work. It would be interesting to look if there was any performance difference over Damien_The_Unbeliever's answer.

Comment: Not really a great answer. As you mention it require only 1 row with null column and the other answers are shorter and doesn't have prerequisites

Answer (score 0):

Use the analytic function :

```
select case when 
    max(field) keep (dense_rank first order by datfin desc nulls first) is null then 1 
    else 0 end as flag 
from MYTABLE;
```

Answer (score -1):

I try to use a union to combine two queries to format the returns you want:

`SELECT recordid, startdate, enddate FROM tmp
 Where enddate is null
 UNION
 SELECT recordid, MIN(startdate), MAX(enddate) FROM tmp GROUP BY recordid`

But I have no idea if the Union would have great impact on the performance