# delete duplicate rows but keep preferred row

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a simple database table

```
create table demo (
  id     integer PRIMARY KEY,
  fv     integer,
  sv     text,
  rel_id integer,
  FOREIGN KEY (rel_id)
  REFERENCES demo(id));
```

and i want to delete all duplicate rows grouped by `fv` and `sv`. Which is already a [fairly popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows) with great answers.
But I need a twist on that scenario. As in cases where `rel_id` is `NULL` I want to keep that row. In any other case anything goes.

So by using the following values

```
insert into demo (id,fv,sv,rel_id)
VALUES (1,1,'somestring',NULL),
       (2,2,'somemorestring',1),
       (3,1,'anotherstring',NULL),
       (4,2,'somemorestring',3),
       (5,1,'somestring',3)
```

Either

```
id | fv |     sv           | rel_id
---+----+------------------+-------
 1 | 1  | 'somestring'     | NULL
 2 | 2  | 'somemorestring' | 1
 3 | 1  | 'anotherstring'  | NULL
```

or

```
id | fv |     sv           | rel_id
---+----+------------------+-------
 1 | 1  | 'somestring'     | NULL
 3 | 1  | 'anotherstring'  | NULL
 4 | 2  | 'somemorestring' | 3
```

would be valid results. Where as

```
id | fv |     sv           | rel_id
---+----+------------------+-------
 3 | 1  | 'anotherstring'  | NULL
 4 | 2  | 'somemorestring' | 3
 5 | 1  | 'somestring'     | 3
```

would not be. As the first entry had `NULL` as `rel_id` which takes presidency above `NOT NULL`.

I currently have this (which is an answer on the basic duplicate question) as a query to remove duplicates but I am not sure how to continue to modify the query to fit my needs.

```
DELETE FROM demo
WHERE  id NOT IN (SELECT min(id) as id
                  FROM demo
                  GROUP BY fv,sv)
```

As as soon as the `NOT NULL` entry is inserted into the database before the `NULL` entry the `NOT NULL` one will not be deleted. It is guaranteed that `rel_id` will always point to an entry where `rel_id` is `NULL` therefore there is no danger of deleting a referenced entry. Further it is guaranteed that there will be no two rows in the same group with `rel_id IS NULL`. Therefore a row with `rel_id IS NULL` is unique for the whole table.

Or as a basic algorithm:

1. Go over all rows and group them by `fv` and `sv`
2. Look into each group for a row where `rel_id IS NULL`. If there is keep that row (and delete the rest). Else pick one row of your choice and delete the rest.

[sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/36d91/1)

Comment: I see you've done serious work on trying to solve, but I can't clearly get the task. Are there conditions you would like to delete records with `rel_id=NULL`? If not, just add `WHERE rel_id IS NOT NULL` to the inner `select`

Comment: @KirillSlatin that would kill any row where there is a `NULL` entry in `rel_id`. I will edit in further explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have worked it out

```
DELETE FROM demo
    WHERE  id NOT IN (SELECT min(id) as id
                      FROM demo AS out_buff
                      WHERE rel_id IS NULL OR
                            NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM demo AS in_buff
                                        WHERE rel_id IS NULL AND
                                              in_buff.fv = out_buff.fv AND
                                              in_buff.sv = out_buff.sv)
                      GROUP BY fv,sv);
```

by selecting in the inner `SELECT` either only the row with the `rel_id` with the value `NULL` or all rows matching on the `GROUP BY` arguments, by using the anti-condition to the existence of a row with `rel_id IS NULL`. But my query looks really ineffective. As a naive assumption would put the running time at at least `O(n^2)`.

Comment: you have 2 nested queries. It might have performance issues on large data sets. If I understood your explanation correctly, you need to [include NULL in your aggregate function MIN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286215/how-can-i-include-null-values-in-a-min-or-max)