# Make MIN(column) return NULL if column contains NULL

Tags: sql

```
SELECT MIN(column) FROM table;
```

will return minimum from **nonnull** elements.

I would like to write a query that will treat `NULL` as if it were the smallest value possible.

I have seen tricks with **dates** using a special value like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32240382/7810882

But what if the column is of type `int` and there is no special value that I can map `NULL` to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using a `case` expression:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = COUNT(COLUMN) THEN MIN(column) END)
FROM table;
```