# Different WHERE clause depending on subquery result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to `SELECT WHERE column` `IS NULL` or `=value` depending on result of subquery.

Here is an example incorrect solution that demonstrates the problem:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE column=(
  SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = COUNT(COLUMN) THEN MIN(column) END)
  FROM table
)
```

When the subquery returns `NULL` the other query will return nothing because `column=NULL` is never true. How do I fix this?

(Subquery source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51341498/7810882)

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: If the solution is rdbms specific then I prefer PostgreSQL

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a3968c/1 , I expect get row with name `a` and if that row wasn't present, row with name `c`. As you wrote, adding `OR column IS NULL` solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question. just add `OR column IS NULL` in `where` clause.

You will get the subquery condition or `column IS NULL` data.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE column= (
  SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = COUNT(COLUMN) THEN MIN(column) END)
  FROM table
) OR column IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking for one row, I would suggest:

```
select t.*
from table t
order by column nulls first
fetch first 1 row only;
```